# How do I remove blank space above h1?

Tags: html, css, fonts, heading

I am busy working on a portfolio website and I am experiencing a strange issue. There is some blank space above al my headings and there is also floating part of the text outside of the heading on the bottom.

I already tried removing margin/padding, changing fonts, changing line-height and changing font-size.

Although I have the feeling that the answer must be quite simple I couldn't find the answer myself.

Screencapture:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/dHpCI.png

Comment: Did you tried to set `margin: 0`?

Comment: it's margin-bottom for all the heading

Comment: Already tried both answers. If you look over at this page: http://dev-environment.nl/ you'll see that it's probably no margin or padding issue.

Comment: You can't, that's just how the font is generated, this falls out of the CSS.

Answer (score 1):

After inspecting your site (http://dev-environment.nl/), i noticed that margin is set to h1. Remove this margin.

Set below values to your css.

```
h1 {
    margin: 0px;
   -webkit-margin-before: 0px;
   -webkit-margin-after: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After checking your site, I think it's your container class which has following css (you have every h1 in container class div):

```
main container{        
padding-left: 20px;
        padding-right: 20px;
        padding-top: 60px;
        padding-bottom: 60px;
}
```

try changing these values.

Answer (score 0):

please add`h1 {line-height: 1.2rem;}`
and add-jest it according to your need